# Move multiple row values in a single row in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have below table

```
TABLE A

| S | D  |
----------
| 1 | 01 |    
| 2 | 01 |
| 2 | 03 |
```

I want my query result in the below format

```
| S | D  |
|1,2| 01 |  
| 2 | 03 |
```

How can I get this in SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with the help of `STUFF` we can achieve this

```
declare @temp table
(
S int,
D nvarchar(10)    
)

insert into @temp values (1,'01')
insert into @temp values (2,'01')
insert into @temp values (2,'03');

SELECT D,

     STUFF(
         (SELECT ',' + CAST(S AS VARCHAR(10))
          FROM @temp
          WHERE D = a.D
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS Remark
FROM @temp AS a
GROUP BY D
```

Comment: Thanks for your support... I have used your query and is working good.